# Python equivalent of unzip -p

Tags: python

Is there a way to do the following directly in python, or do I need to use a `subprocess` call?

```
$ unzip -p /Users/david/Desktop/new2.xlsx xl/sharedStrings.xml > shared3.xml
```

Something better than:

```
s=subprocess.run('unzip -p /Users/david/Desktop/new2.xlsx xl/sharedStrings.xml', shell=True, stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
print(s)
```

Comment: Potentially related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3451111/unzipping-files-in-python

Comment: This is your exact use case.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10568468/merge-multiple-zip-files-into-a-single-zip-file-in-python

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Unzipping files in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3451111/unzipping-files-in-python)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the [zipfile](https://docs.python.org/3/library/zipfile.htm) module:

```py
from pathlib import Path
from zipfile import ZipFile

with ZipFile("/Users/david/Desktop/new2.xlsx") as zip_file:
    with zip_file.open("xl/sharedStrings.xml") as file_in_zip:
        Path("shared3.xml").write_bytes(file_in_zip.read())
```